# Firebase url of dynamic pages

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

This is probably a dumb question, but I can't figure out how the Firebase functions must be used.

I'm new to Firebase. I created a Firebase projet by following some tutorials. My final goal is to create dynamic websites with authentification and database. I'm very familiar with PHP, node.js, mySql... But I am a bit confused with Firebase.

My project use static pages hosting and functions. Both works, but they do no share the same URL when deploy.

- Static pages are served at https://fir-87878.web.app/
- Functions are served at https://us-central1-fir-87878.cloudfunctions.net/app

I'm used to mix on the same domain static and dynamic pages. Since the functions and the hosting are not are at the same URL, I don't understand how to create dynamic pages. More generally, I'm probably missing something about the philosophy of the functions.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: The Firebase Functions are basically Serverless Functions. You should research more on what they are if you don't know what they are and what they do. Here is a good explanation in a hubspot article: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/serverless-functions

Comment: @MilanLakhani I read the page you linked, but it's not more clear. I know what are microservices, but I still don't understand how to serve dynamic pages on the main domain.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation on serving dynamic content](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)? Please do that if you haven't already.  After that, could you edit the question to explain what you're stuck on *from the perspective of what you learn there*?  Just saying "I don't understand how to create dynamic pages" doesn't really tell us what you're confused about or where you are stuck.  There are also countless tutorials and examples out there to follow if you want to learn.  I suggest making an attempt at anything at all, show what you tried, and explain what's wrong.

Comment: Okay, So what I think you want from "dynamic pages" is to learn how to use the serverless functions in your frontend app. Please correct me if I am wrong.  In that case follow the firebase documentation on how to use in on clientside. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#set_up_your_client_development_environment

Comment: @DougStevenson I already spend hours reading the Google documentation. I also configured, emulated and deployed a test application (the two links in my questions are my Firebase app). My question is not about the technical part, my question is about the architecture. I expected something similar to Node.js / Express applications where you can serve static and dynamic pages from the same server. But I understand this is different on Firebase. What if I want to  serve a static page at `https://fir-87878.web.app/static.html` and a dynamic page at `https://fir-87878.web.app/dynamic.html` ?

Comment: You should explain in your question (by editing it to include more details) what you've done so far (show code, give instructions we can use the follow along) and explain what you're trying to do in that context. If you tried something that doesn't work, explain what it's doing that's different than what you expect.  Your question right now is just too broad to respond to meaningfully. There are literally any number of possible ways to accomplish your goal - we need to know the path you've gone down first so we know if you're even doing something that's sensible.

Comment: I will point out that the documentation I linked you to before shows you how to match URLs that are handled by Firebase Hosting and forward them to a function.  If you are not writing configuration to forward Firebase Hosting URLs to Cloud Functions code, you will never get dynamic content served from your Firebase Hosting web address.

Comment: @DougStevenson I think I'm starting to understand. What I was missing is that we can rewrite URL to functions. That was not clear for me and the Firebase documentation is not always clear. Now I think I have some troubles with Express, but this is another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is that you can redirect some URLs to functions. Add the following lines to `firebase.json`:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
      "source": "/app/**",
      "dynamicLinks": true,
      "function": "app"                
  }
]
```

and the following to `functions/index.js`:

```
// Create an app with Express
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// Any URL starting with /app/id will call this function
app.get("/app/:id", (req, res) => {
    res.send("ID = " + req.params.id);
});
```

If it is not clear, check this page. Everything you need to understand is detailed: https://lucidar.me/en/firebase/host-a-dynamic-website-on-firebase/

[image: Dynamic URL with FireBase]